# iterating through nested Custom Objects in c# (tree)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, tree

I am working on projects which requires me to represent data in a tree format, I have tried iterating through objects, but facing trouble accessing and assigning data to inner objects, the main class looks like this

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Child { get; set; }
    public Node()
    {
        this.Child = new List<Node>();
    }
}
```

and there is a function which will take List and create Tree of Node class, by iterating through the list

```
public Node NodeLister(myclass value)
    {
        List<Node> holder = new List<Node>();
        Node head = new Node();
        Node temp;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (MenuElements item in value.value)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
               head =new Node { Name = item.Name };
            }
            else
            {
                temp = new Node { Name = item.Name };
                holder.Add(temp);
                holder = holder[holder.IndexOf(temp)].Child;
            }
            i++;
        }
        head.Child = holder;
        return head;
     }
```

the part

```
 holder = holder[holder.IndexOf(temp)].Child;
```

has to somehow have pointer kind of effect as this statement is directly assigning the value and erasing the previous data rather than iterating through it. myclass Class looks something like below.

```
public class myclass
{

    public List<MenuElements> value { get; set; }
}

public class MenuElements
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

I know that this will not create a tree but solving this issue will help me moving forward, and creating the tree. any help would be appreciated

Comment: You should not make the list property writeable outside the class, make it readonly by making the setter private, then manipulate the list instead of replacing it, easier to reason about what happens.

Comment: You need to do this recursively. It's a little bit difficult at first, but doing something like this without recursion is harder. And recursion is very useful to know. It's worth the effort.

Comment: @EdPlunkett can you please provide me any example? a rough logic can help. thanks

Comment: It is not clear to me from your example what your final tree should look like.  Is it supposed to be linear?  I.e. the first element in the list is the root, the second element is the child of the root, etc?